# Convert/Change specific column class without subsetting

Tags: r, class

windows 7, R 3.1.0 64bit

I have a data.frame with 45 obs. and 46 variables and with all column classes as characters. How can I change only one or two column classes to numeric, for example, without subsetting that column. Basically, I want to maintain the data.frame with the new classes. Is there like a 1 line code to do this?

lapply gives me a subset of the data, which I DO NOT want, or maybe I missed sth with that function. You may demonstrate using mtcars dataset for e.g.

I have searched online for hours.

Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: lets say you have x column in df that you want to convert to numeric then code would be, `df$x = as.numeric(df$x)`.... If this is not what you want then try to give more information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think the columns should be numeric, make sure you know why R converted them to character. It's best to get the data import as clean as possible rather than fixing mistakes after the fact. Nevertheless, you can convert columns with a simple loop

```
dd <- mtcars
for(col in c("disp","hp")) {
    dd[[col]] <- as.character(dd[[col]])
}
str(dd)
```

Since everything in `mtcars` is already numeric, I converted two fields to character. You could use `lapply` here too but this is one of the **few** cases where I think a for loop is more straight forward in my opinion.

Comment: `cols <- c("disp","hp"); mtcars[cols] <- lapply(mtcars[cols],as.character);` doesn't seem too complex and reduces the operation to only one assignment.

Comment: I just hate having the extra variable lying around i'll never use again. Seems redundant. That's just my opinion.

Comment: Like the `col` variable that will be lying around containing "hp" when you use the `for` loop?

Comment: I keep hoping some day R will be smart enough to get rid of loop specific variables.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a column "col1" of your data.frame df to numeric:

```
class(df[["col1"]]) <- "numeric"
```

Comment: @user3682558, yes, it does.